# How to create parallel dates graph in kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have graph in my kibana 4 like this:
[image]

But I want this graph in below format:

[image]

How can I do this in Kibana 4? Any pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not available (yet?).  See [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1244).